# Can I choose a heatsink based on its thermal design power (TDP) for cooling LED chips?

Tags: led, heatsink, power-dissipation, cooling

I am confused about TDP ratings and what they refer to actually.
The reason I am confused is because most modern CPUs and GPUs, although not ideal, are able to sustain very high temperatures (80 C or even above).

In my projects, I need to cool bunch of high power LEDs.
I'd like to keep the LEDs under 70 degrees celcius but 60 or less would be even better.

My application areas have very constant (known) ambient temperatures (between 20 to 36 C, basically indoors).

**My questions is:**

If I have a 100w rated LED that I drive at 32 volts x 2 amps (64 watts total), could I use a CPU cooler with 75 watt TDP to keep it under 70 degrees celcius in ambient conditions?

I have done my research but could not get the answer I need.
Your helps is much appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: TDP is roughly how much power the cooler can handle while keeping the CPU core under 80 or 90C. How cool it will keep an LED depends on it's thermal resistance, which is probably higher than a cpu die.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linear de-rating would be appropriate since the main cooling mechanism is Newtonian cooling, not radiation.

So let's look at a heatsink with 75W TDP, between an 80°C device and 30°C ambient, and you want to keep the LEDs down to 60°C in the same 30°C ambient temperature...

Now the heatsink sees a 50°C temperature rise at 75W TDP, (or a thermal resistance of 0.67°C/watt. Thermal resistance is the usual way of rating heatsinks other than CPU coolers).

If you decide to allow a temperature rise of 30°C for your device (60°C LED - 30°C ambient) ... that is 3/5 or 60% of the heatsink's desgn point : it follows that it can provide 3/5 of the 75W cooling, i.e. 45W.

(Crosscheck using the thermal resistance : 0.67°C/W * 45W = 30°C.)

Comment: @Transistor Thanks : I hate markup; the fact it's different between here and Stack Overflow doesn't help!

Comment: You're welcome. I left out the spaces between the numbers and units for you as I know you're not quite ready for them! ("5nuts" or "5 nuts"?)

Comment: @BrianDrummond thank you for this very easy to understand explanation. Just to be clear though, where does the 80 C number come from? I am not sure if I understand what an 80 C device is. Is it the maximum temperature that should be supported by CPUs as I mentioned earlier? Or does it mean "once a device reaches 80 C.." Thanks again

Comment: Where does 80C come from? From your question. I have no idea if it's the right number; I was just working with your example figures. 30C was just a reasonable number within your range of ambient temperatures.